# get usb location on android device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an app using flash cc as3. In the app, it load external swf from `documentsDirectory`. It works fine on tablets and phones. My boss brings me this new android projector device. Now app could not locate the `documentsDirectory` in that device. I tried `userDirectory`. It also didn't work. The android projector device's usb location is `/mnt/usb/sda1/myfolder`. I tried to manually set the location of the file, it also didn't work. Is there anyway I could find the location of the usb in as3? I tried 
`var volumes = StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes();` to get all the available volumes but it show errors. Is it possible to copy files to usb drive using as3? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The text of the mentioned errors would be helpful.

Comment: might be anything to do with permissions?

Comment: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: what kind of permission do I need ?

Comment: is `StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes()` just for air for desktop ?